# Audio Clip not working on Collision when destroying an object

Tags: unity, c#, audio

So I made a game where you shoot a laser and if it hits the enemy it makes an explosion sound and destroys the enemy. The only thing is whenever I try to get the audio to play it doesn't which I assume is caused by the enemy being destroyed. I have tried to use the Play() methods and PlayOneShot() methods but they both don't seem to help me out.

This is my current code:

```html
public AudioClip explosion;
public AudioSource explosionAudioSource;

public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
    
    void Start() {
    explosionAudioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }
        if (this.tag == "Enemy" && other.tag == "Laser")
        {
            explosionAudioSource.PlayOneShot(explosion);
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            Instantiate(enemyExplosion, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z), Quaternion.identity);
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            uiManager.UpdateScore();
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: How exactly do you expect the audio source to play sound when you've destroyed it? This is like taking a sledgehammer to your speakers then wondering why the music stopped. Did you try playing the sound from an audio source that you're *not* destroying?

Comment: I did try with 3 other audio files, they all work properly. Just when I assign the audio to play before the enemy dies is when it destroys.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix my problem by instantiating a prefab with the audio source onto it and have it play on awake when the object was instantiated it would play the sound perfectly.